# More than one file was found with OS independent path org/springframework

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Hey guys I'm using android studio 3.0.1 and I have a problem when running my project ever since i added a maven dependency.

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.jake.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    }


}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:+'
}
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.2.4'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.github.pabloo99.xmlsoccer:xmlsoccer:0.0.6'
}
```

when i now run this i get the error: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.

> More than one file was found with OS independent path 'org/springframework/web/servlet/config/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd'

I have looked around elsewhere on stackoverflow and have found solutions but the people dont seem to have the org/springframework error. I have tried deleting the .gradle file and cleaning and building, however when i rebuild the project i get the error: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

which i thought would have been solved with: multiDexEnabled true

any ideas on how to get this working? if you need more information please let me know. I am very new to this. Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: did you get your answer?

Comment: @Riddhi No I didn't. But I scrapped the project. Would be interested if you know what the problem is though!

Comment: Actually, I also wanted to know the answer if you have your solution. But, Now, I also found answer for my problem